# удалить строки по интервалам времени pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Приветствую) Не могу найти как это сделать. есть такая вот таблица. Какой командой удалить можно строки которые поподают в интервал с 20:00 до 21:00?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/398802)

Comment: можете уточнить открытость/закрытость границ интервала `20:00, 21:00`? Что делать с точным попаданием - `20:00` и `21:00` - удалять оба, оставлять левую или правую границу?

Comment: Уже на раз вам писал в комментариях, данные публикуются текстом, не картинкой. У вас с этим какие-то трудности?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так должно работать, хотя 21:00 тут останется, но принцип думаю понятен:

```
df = df.loc[(df.index.hour < 20) | (df.index.hour >= 21)]
```

Чтобы совсем точно сделать сравнение, сделайте так:

```
import datetime
df = df.loc[(df.index.time < datetime.time(20)) | (df.index.time > datetime.time(21))]
```

В целом смысл в том, что нужно не удалять не нужное, а наоборот - оставить только нужное, перезаписав `DataFrame`.

Comment: пишет 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: @AlihanUrumov, замените `df.index.dt.hour` -> `df.index.hour`. NOTE: в моем решении такую замену делать __не надо__

Comment: Да, `dt` не нужно, я проверил. Но второй вариант пока не работает

Comment: @AlihanUrumov Вроде и более точный вариант я подобрал )

Answer (score 4):

Пример данных:

```
In [41]: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:             {"val": np.random.randint(10, size=10)},
    ...:             index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01 19:00:00", periods=10, freq="30T")
    ...:         )
    ...:

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
                     val
2020-01-01 19:00:00    7
2020-01-01 19:30:00    6
2020-01-01 20:00:00    8
2020-01-01 20:30:00    2
2020-01-01 21:00:00    6
2020-01-01 21:30:00    9
2020-01-01 22:00:00    5
2020-01-01 22:30:00    2
2020-01-01 23:00:00    1
2020-01-01 23:30:00    7
```

решение для удаления дат из интервала `[20:00, 21:00)` (NOTE: правая граница интервала открытая):

```
res = df.query("index.dt.hour != 20")
```

результат:

```
In [59]: res
Out[59]:
                     val
date
2020-01-01 19:00:00    7
2020-01-01 19:30:00    6
2020-01-01 21:00:00    6
2020-01-01 21:30:00    9
2020-01-01 22:00:00    5
2020-01-01 22:30:00    2
2020-01-01 23:00:00    1
2020-01-01 23:30:00    7
```

Comment: Из постановки задачи мне показалось, что 21:15 и т.д. нужно сохранить. Но не уверен )

Comment: @CrazyElf, сделал как у вас - с "открытой" правой границей интервала ;)

Comment: Спасибо за генерацию df, я разобрался как целиком время сравнить )

Comment: @CrazyElf, пытался найти функцию обратную `df.time_between()` - не нашел. Пришлось подсмотреть в исходниках как она устроена - в итоге пришел к [такому варианту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1178252/211923) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Вариант удаляющий даты с учетом обоих концов интервала - т.е. и `20:00` и `21:00` будут удалены из результата:

```
idxs = df.index.indexer_between_time(
    "20:00", 
    "21:00", 
    include_start=True,
    include_end=True)

res = df.iloc[pd.Index(np.arange(len(df))).difference(idxs)]
```

---

```
In [75]: res
Out[75]:
                     val
date
2020-01-01 19:00:00    7
2020-01-01 19:30:00    6
2020-01-01 21:30:00    9
2020-01-01 22:00:00    5
2020-01-01 22:30:00    2
2020-01-01 23:00:00    1
2020-01-01 23:30:00    7
```